# How to mock object in jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a function of an object with Jest and Typescript and it just does not work. Here is a short version of what I have:

```
// myModule.ts

export const Foo = {
  doSomething: () => {
    // ... does something
    console.log('original implementation');
  }
}
```

Then in my test:

```
jest.mock('.myModule.ts', () => {
  return {
    Foo: {
      doSomething: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        console.log('mock implementation')
      })
    }
  }
})

// .. further down in the test
Foo.doSomething();
```

Shouldn't the `console.log('mock implementation')` be called when I call `Foo.doSomething()`? It doesn't error and it's not calling the original implementation anymore, but it's also not calling my mockImplementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
import { Foo } from './foo';

jest
  .spyOn(Foo, 'doSomething')
  .mockImplementation(() => console.log('mock implementation'));

Foo.doSomething();
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that worked right away and was so simple!

Answer (score 0):

After switching to jest 26.6, I found that none of these worked outside of tests (had been doing it directly below my imports, outside of any `describe` or `it` call). If I wanted any kind of mock implementation, I had to set it in the test, or in a `beforeEach`. If anyone can supply a link to the documentation on this, I'd be obliged.